# can you help me to optimize this code

Tags: python

can you help me to optimize this code

```
def calc_potential(time, firstsale, lastsale, sold, supplied):
    retval = []
    for t, f, l, c, s in zip(time, firstsale, lastsale, sold, supplied):
        try:
            if s > c:
                retval.append(c)
            else:
                s = (l - t).total_seconds() / 3600.
                d = ((t - f).total_seconds() / 3600.) / c
                retval.append(s / d + c)
        except:
            retval.append(None)

    return retval
```

Comment: We (maybe) help fix broken code. We're not an optimization service.

Comment: What aspects of this do you think can be optimized?

Comment: [Code View](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour) may be a better choice for your request. Please read the help page carefully however, and make sure your post is on-topic.

Comment: everything can  improve it  while keep it correct

Comment: One thing: Don't call your variables `c`. `d`, `f`. `l`. `s` and `t`. Use meaningful names

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in mind some of the comments i.e. this is not for optimizing but rather fixing broken code, I can point you in the right direction:

To replace this section of code:

```
if s > c:
  retval.append(c)
```

For something more efficient, try list comprehension:

```
retval= [c for c, s in zip(sold, supplied) if s>c]
```

If you do something similar for the code in the else statement as well, and combine both lists. You will have what you want in one possible way.